# Basic multisocket program

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to implement a multisocket program (both client and server). After a little googling, I found that a good idea to do it is to implement Runnable. Now I suppose that each thread I create and use .start() is a different client (correct me if I'm wrong).

What I find difficult is to understand 2 things:

-Which is the exact line that accepts data? I guess it's not the Server.accept() method since this method is used to initiate a connection with the specific client (by making a new thread as mentioned before).

-How can I accept more than 1 packet (let's say it's a string)?

Answer (score 2):

A little correction, every new thread you create and start with `start()` will be a new server thread handling a new client.

> Which is the exact line that accepts data?

To accept data from client, you'll have to wrap the client's input stream into some input stream and then call the input stream's respective read function.

```
void readx(Socket con)
{
    String line=new String();
    BufferedReader bin=  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
    while((line = bin.readLine()) != null) //Read new lines coming from the server
        System.out.println(line);
}
```

This is just an example, you can have other InputStream wrappers like `DataInputStream` and their respective read functions.

> How can I accept more than 1 packet (let's say it's a string)?

The above snippet will continuously accept data from client(can be any number of lines) till the client sends an End of Stream character.